# Problems configuring site on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, git, pythonanywhere

I am trying deploy a test web app on PythonAnywhere by pulling my code from my Github repo using a helper tool by PythonAnywhere. I used this command:

```
$ pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.8 https://github.com/<your-github-username>/repository.git
```

Then after a prompt for my username and password ( had to use a token because it is required) and putting them in I got this error:

```
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Username/Myrepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Username/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 49, in <module>
    main(
  File "/home/Username/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 31, in main
    project.download_repo(repo_url, nuke=nuke),
  File "/home/Username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 20, in download_repo
    subprocess.check_call(['git', 'clone', repo, str(self.project_path)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/username/repo.git', '/home/username/username.pythonanywhere.com']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that your GitHub token is valid and not expired.

Comment: I used it immediatly after generating it.

Comment: What's the scope of the token?

Comment: It was for git repo.